# adodb .FIND question

Tags: sql, mysql, excel, vba, adodb

i am using excel to connect to a mysql database

i am doing this:

```
rs.Find "rowid='105'"
If Not rs.EOF Then cn.Execute "delete  from batchinfo where rowid='105'"
```

and it works well

however, i need to be able to match data on multiple columns for example like this:

```
rs. find "rowid='105'" and "something='sometext'" and "somethingelse='moretext'"
```

i need to know whether or not rs.find matched ALL of the data.

how can i do this?

according to this i can't:
https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-1045830.html#

however perhaps there's a way i can rs.execute "some select statement" 
can someone help with this?

would this do the trick for me and then i would check EOF:

```
rs.Filter "LastName='Adams' and FirstName='Lamont'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just do it all in SQL like :

```
DELETE  FROM batchinfo where rowid='105'
AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM batchinfo WHERE rowid='105' and something='sometext' and somethingelse='moretext')
```

Comment: ben i dont really understand the syntax can you please explain?

Comment: error: you can't specify target table batchinfo for update in from clause

Comment: Why the exists bit? Why not just `DELETE  FROM batchinfo where rowid='105' and something='sometext' and somethingelse='moretext'` ? The recordsaffected property can be used to check the records deleted.